# Users table association with users_metadata table appears broken

Tags: theme-development, database, users, phpmyadmin

I noticed an issue after deploying a custom theme build to a Go Daddy Managed WordPress installation (client's request, RIP) wherein users created by the admin account in the WP back-end weren't showing up in the list of users.

They appear in the users database, but there appears to be no associated references in the `users_metadata` table (there are entries for the admin account, but that's it).

The users table says it has no primary key assigned - I'm not sure if that's part of the problem. I'm assuming that the user ID should be the primary key but clearly I'm no SQL pro here.

My client needs to be able to create users so his staff can upload content. What tree should I be barking up to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the users table the primary key should be ID (auto-increment) and the `user_login`, `user_nicename` and `user_email` fields should be indexed.

In the `usermeta` table the `umeta_id` should be primary key (auto-increment) and the `umeta_id` and `meta_key` fields should be indexed.

Comment: Thanks. After following these steps, database behaviour is as expected.